# CreateJS FPS drop when calling stage.update

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

I'm making a game using CreateJS. On desktop my FPS is good but when I try to play this game on mobile (for example : iPhone 4) the FPS drops seriously.

I'm trying to figure out why but

Some code

My Canvas

```
 <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Setup

```
 this.canvas = "gameCanvas";    
 this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
 var context = this.stage.canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
 this.gameLoopBind = this.gameLoop.bind(this);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.gameLoopBind);
```

GameLoop

```
// some extra code 
this.stage.update();
```

When I comment the code 'this.stage.update()' my FPS on mobile/tablet is good...

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong...

**EXTRA CODE**
Play the game here => [f.cowb.eu/mora/chick-ins](https://f.cowb.eu/mora/chick-ins)

Gameloop Function

```
 Game.prototype.gameLoop = function (e) {


    if (this.running) {
        this.timer++;
        this.timer2++;

        if (this.timer2 > 30) {
            if (this.lastSnack + this.timeBewteen < this.stopwatch.seconds) {

                var height = (this.topSnack) ? 150 : 300;
                this.lastSnack = this.stopwatch.seconds;
                new Snack(this, this.timer, height);
                this.topSnack = this.topSnack ? false : true;
            }

            if (this.timer > (this.lastPostive + 300)) {
                this.lastPostive = this.timer;
                publisher.publish('showMessage',
                    this.positiveImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.positiveImages.length)],
                    common.lang,
                    'right');
            }
            this.timer2 = 0;
        }
    }

    this.stage.update();
};
```

New Snack 
 You can find the code for creating a new snack here => http://jsfiddle.net/9ofpqq3z/

Here we create a new snack and animate it.

Comment: if you disable `this.stage.update()` then you are not rendering anything at all apart from the first frame (if you call `stage.update()` at least once outside the game loop) so that's why you get the FPS increase. can you post some more of the code, so we can see exactly what you render?

Comment: You can check the game here => f.cowb.eu/mora/chick-ins


Some extra code above

Comment: try using RAF mode, see the timing section of this [link](http://createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/)

Comment: @HaykoKoryun just adding this ?

createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED;

Comment: yes, before you set the fps, that might make the rendering much smoother. try it out and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope still around the 15FPS instead of 50-60FPS..

http://i.imgur.com/UccXz5s.png

http://i.imgur.com/zP5FZyP.png

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the architecture of the game, I would suggest that you draw the game elements on separate canvases as opposed to the way you have it right now where everything is on one canvas.

Place the TV parts that don't get redrawn often (or at all) on one canvas, and then the moving elements on a separate canvas.

That should help bring the frame rate up.

Also, you can take a look at the following set of slides on how to improve performance on mobile devices when using the canvas:
http://www.slideshare.net/DavidGoemans/html5-performance-optimization

Comment: The TV parts and the lights etc are not on a canvas. Because the won't get redrawn.

The moving elements on a separate canvas per element or all the moving elements on one canvas?